# Split vector into chunks by delimiter

Tags: r, split

I have the following structure:

```
timestamp = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
values = c(1337,42,NA,23,67,2,NA,NA,NA,5)
df = data.frame(timestamp,values)

#    timestamp values
# 1          1   1337
# 2          2     42
# 3          3     NA
# 4          4     23
# 5          5     67
# 6          6      2
# 7          7     NA
# 8          8     NA
# 9          9     NA
# 10        10      5
```

Now I want to know, how many coherent chunks there are (in this case 3: [1337,42] [23,67,2] and [5]. Maybe I can even split it to sub data frames or something like this?

Comment: So you want to count rows that have NA before them (plus one for the first row)?

Comment: @Bulat Yes, plus the first one of course. Would do it with a simple loop, but my instructor told me, loops are bad for performance in R (don't know why).

Comment: you should try loop version and say `data.table` + `shift` to see why

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-April/237031.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As rawr suggested in the comments i am using the following solution:

```
foo <- function( x ){
   idx <- 1 + cumsum( is.na( x ) )
   not.na <- ! is.na( x )
   result <- split( x[not.na], idx[not.na] )
   return(result)
}
```

Reasons:

- It was the first solution
- It works
- I understand it
- It does not use any packages/libraries.

Still thanks for all answers!

I will mark this as answered as soo as i can (in two days).

Comment: It could even be simplified a bit more - `f <- function(x) {nax <- is.na(x); split(x[!nax], cumsum(nax)[!nax]) }`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to do this with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
timestamp = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
values = c(1337,42,NA,23,67,2,NA,NA,NA,5)
dt = data.table(timestamp,values)
dt[, previous:=shift(values)]
res <- dt[!is.na(values) & is.na(previous), .N]
res
# [1] 3
```

As performance was mentioned in the comment, here is the benchmark of solutions (on 1e5 rows):

```
    Unit: milliseconds
          expr        min        lq      mean     median        max neval
     dt[shift]   3.966346   4.03936   4.90822   4.728635   7.345617    10
 split[cumsum]  15.693565  17.38094  18.79429  17.739346  31.370630    10
           rle  42.375227  42.65068  45.82327  45.326625  51.473468    10
         dplyr 645.156377 655.90239 676.37797 678.966334 711.393856    10
```

Comment: Would you be able to benchmark the simplified version of @Obererpel 's answer below? It should speed up a bit with not having to calculate `is.na(x)` twice and avoiding assigning to `result`

Comment: sure, why not, I am not testing solutions though

Answer (score 3):

Using library `dplyr`, you can do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
timestamp = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
values = c(1337,42,NA,23,67,2,NA,NA,NA,5)
df = data.frame(timestamp,values)
df %>%
  mutate(id = cumsum(is.na(values) | is.na(lag(values)))) %>%
  filter(!is.na(values)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(chunks = paste(values, collapse = ',')) %>%
  select(-id)
```

Output is:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 1]

   chunks
    <chr>
1 1337,42
2 23,67,2
3       5
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `rle` and `rleid` function:

```
library(data.table)
values = c(1337,42,NA,23,67,2,NA,NA,NA,5)
split(values, rleid(is.na(values)))[rle(!is.na(values))$values]
$`1`
[1] 1337   42

$`3`
[1] 23 67  2

$`5`
[1] 5
```

Comment: You need `library(data.table)` for `rleid`, right? Perhaps good to include in the code.